# array_merge based on different column names

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have 2 arrays with one that has a column "order_id" and one that is "orders_id".

These are pulled from json so I can't change the name of the column.

I was hoping this would work but it does not seem to do anything:

```
$tracked[] = array_merge($json['order_id'],$orders['orders_id'] );
print_r($tracked);
```

sample array data:
$orders

```
   Array ( [0] => Array ( [orders_id] => 44925 [customers_email_address] => sample@gmail.com [customers_name] => sample name ) [1] => Array ( [orders_id] => 44923 [customers_email_address] => sample@gmail.com [customers_name] => John Lynch ) [2] => Array ( [orders_id] => 44917 [customers_email_address] => sample@yahoo.com [customers_name] => sample name ) [3] => Array ( [orders_id] => 44915 [customers_email_address] => email@gmail.com [customers_name] => name sample )
```

$json:

```
[7] => Array ( [id] => sample [status] => inducted [batch_id] => 1026819 [to_name] => sample name [to_address_1] => sample address [to_address_2] => [to_city] => DANBURY [to_province_code] => WI [to_postal_code] => 54830 [to_country_code] => US [to_phone] => 7155660005 [return_name] => sample address [return_address_1] => 2045 NIAGARA FALLS BLVD STE 4 [return_address_2] => [return_city] => NIAGARA FALLS [return_province_code] => NY [return_postal_code] => 14304-1675 [return_country_code] => US [return_phone] => 1234321312 [package_contents] => merchandise [description] => 1 x items [value] => 159.17 [value_currency] => USD [order_id] => 42816 [order_store] => [package_type] => thick_envelope [size_unit] => cm [size_x] => 44 [size_y] => 35 [size_z] => 8 [weight_unit] => kg [weight] => 1.3 [is_insured] => [is_insurance_requested] => [is_media_mail_requested] => [is_signature_requested] => [postage_type] => usps_priority [carrier] => usps [carrier_tracking_code] => 12343232324 [tracking_url] => https://chitchats.com/tracking/sa,ple [ship_date] => 2020-10-09 [purchase_amount] => 15.80 [provincial_tax] => [provincial_tax_label] => [federal_tax] => [federal_tax_label] => [postage_fee] => 14.95 [insurance_fee] => [delivery_fee] => 0.85 [created_at] => 2020-10-09T14:34:54.130-04:00 [postage_label_png_url] => https://chitchats.com/labels/shipments/sample.png [postage_label_zpl_url] => https://chitchats.com/labels/shipments/saples.zpl [rates] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [postage_type] => usps_parcel_select [postage_carrier_type] => usps [postage_description] => USPS Parcel Select® [signature_confirmation_description] => [delivery_time_description] => 3-14 estimated business days [tracking_type_description] => Full tracking included [is_insured] => [purchase_amount] => 14.64 [provincial_tax] => [provincial_tax_label] => [federal_tax] => [federal_tax_label] => [postage_fee] => 14.64 [insurance_fee] => [delivery_fee] => 0.85 [payment_amount] => 15.49 ) [1] => Array ( [postage_type] => usps_priority [postage_carrier_type] => usps [postage_description] => USPS Priority Mail® [signature_confirmation_description] => [delivery_time_description] => 3-5 estimated business days [tracking_type_description] => Full tracking included [is_insured] => [purchase_amount] => 14.95 [provincial_tax] => [provincial_tax_label] => [federal_tax] => [federal_tax_label] => [postage_fee] => 14.95 [insurance_fee] => [delivery_fee] => 0.85 [payment_amount] => 15.80 ) [2] => Array ( [postage_type] => usps_express [postage_carrier_type] => usps [postage_description] => USPS Priority Mail Express® [signature_confirmation_description] => [delivery_time_description] => Up to 3 estimated business days [tracking_type_description] => Full tracking included [is_insured] => [purchase_amount] => 64.03 [provincial_tax] => [provincial_tax_label] => [federal_tax] => [federal_tax_label] => [postage_fee] => 64.03 [insurance_fee] => [delivery_fee] => 0.85 [payment_amount] => 64.88 ) ) )
```

My goal is to merge the two arrays based on the order_id and orders_id columns in both of the above sample data.

my goal really is to have a single array with:
order_id
customers_name
email_address
carrier_tracking_code

maybe there is a better way of doing that instead of the merge i tried. now that I am typing it out I think i should maybe somehow loop through both and put into the same array but I would still need to find the matching order_id to do that.

Comment: Can't change the name? ... before decoding the json, you CAN definitely use `str_replace` to convert orders_id to order_id (or vice-versa) within the json string. That's at least one way, I'm sure there are other ways, such as key replacement.

Comment: @PaulT. ok you are definitely correct. I now have them the same name. but trying to use array_merge just puts the arrays together and is not even using the same column name. using array_interesect somewhat works, but is giving me an array of just the order_id and email address (not the data from the other array, tracking number)

Comment: Try using `array_merge_recursive`.